# Do the left half and right halves of the diaphragm undergo the same displacement during breathing?

Tags: human-anatomy

Do the left half and right halves of the diaphragm of a normal person move exactly the same distance between inhaling and exhaling?

Comment: Did you check diaphragm muscle images? They are fairly symmetrical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short answer is that the displacement of the right and left part of the diaphragm during breathing ***may* not be the same.**

**ASYMMETRY**

[Thoracic diaphragm (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thoracic_diaphragm):

> In humans, *the diaphragm is slightly asymmetric*—its right half is
>   higher up (superior) to the left half, since the large liver rests
>   beneath the right half of the diaphragm. There is also a theory that
>   the diaphragm is lower on the other side due to the presence of the
>   heart.

[Genetic specification of left–right asymmetry in the diaphragm muscles and their motor innervation (PubMed)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5481184/):

> The diaphragm muscle is essential for breathing in mammals. *Its
>   asymmetric elevation during contraction* correlates with morphological
>   features suggestive of inherent left–right (L/R) asymmetry.

**EXCURSION**

Excursion (displacement during breathing) of the right and left part of  the diaphragm may or may not be the same, which may differ from case to case.

[Manual evaluation of the diaphragm muscle (PubMed)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4993263/):

> In most cases, the diaphragm shows a symmetrical respiratory excursion
>   of ~2–10 cm...

[Imaging of the Diaphragm: Anatomy and Function (RadioGraphics)](https://pubs.rsna.org/doi/full/10.1148/rg.322115127):

> The excursion may be somewhat asymmetric and there may be a slight
>   delay or lag on one side, typically the right.